# Determinant of symmetric matrix $(A-\lambda I)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

If we have a matrix $(A-\lambda I)$ which is:

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1-\lambda & -1 & 2 \\ 
-1 & 1-\lambda & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$

Then it's determinant can be written as : $(-1)^n(\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)(\lambda-\lambda_3)$. In this case what will $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ be equal to? And how do we determine it's value given that the matrix is symmetric?

Comment: $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are the three eigenvalues of the matrix.  You have to compute the determinant of the matrix you have given, it is a function of $\lambda$, a polynomial of degree three, so you factor it into linear factors, to get the equivalence.

Comment: Solve the equation $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant yes we have to compute it via a polynomial but that is a much longer method. This method suggested that we could easily determine the eigenvalues by merely looking at the matrix but I don't know how to use this method.

Comment: Ah probably because it is symmetric.  Try to look up what is known about the eigenvalues of symmetric matrices.

Comment: I looked it up and I don't think there's a real easy way to just read them off from the matrix.  If the matrix was upper triangular then yes, but not in the form given.  Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1-\lambda & -1 & 2 \\ 
-1 & 1-\lambda & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array} \right)
$ = $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2-\lambda & -2+\lambda & 0 \\ 
-1 & 1-\lambda & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array} \right)
=(-2+\lambda)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 1-\lambda & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array} \right) =
(-2+\lambda)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & -\lambda & 2 \\ 
2 & 4 & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array} \right)= (-1)(-2+\lambda)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 -\lambda & 2 \\ 
4 & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array} \right)
= (-1)(-2+\lambda)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
4 -\lambda & 4 -\lambda \\ 
4 & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array} \right)= 
(-2+\lambda)(\lambda-4)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1\\ 
4 & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array} \right)
= 
(-2+\lambda)(\lambda-4)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1\\ 
2+\lambda & 2-\lambda \\ 
\end{array} \right)=(-2+\lambda)(\lambda-4)(2-\lambda)=(-1)(\lambda-2)(\lambda-4)(\lambda-2)
$ Therefore, 
$\lambda_1=2,\lambda_2=2,\lambda_3=4$.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply expand the determinant, which is not that much work for a $3\times 3$.

Or you could set $\lambda=0$ and *guess* the eigenvalues of the resulting matrix, for example $(1\,{-1}\,0)^T$ and $(1\,1\,1)^T$ are obvious eigenvectors of eigenvalue $2$. The fact that the matrix is symmetric guarantees us that all eigenvalues will be real.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** : Solve $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, with:
$$\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&-1&2\\-1&1-\lambda&2\\2&2&2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=(1-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&2\\2&2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}-(-1)\begin{vmatrix}-1&2\\2&2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}+2\begin{vmatrix}-1&1-\lambda\\2&2\end{vmatrix}$$